# I need help comparing numbers in defrule with multislot objects in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I have the following code

```
(deftemplate choice-evaluation
(slot x_front)
(slot y_left)



(deftemplate es_result
(slot classp)
(slot classr)
(slot nr) )

(defrule MAIN::one
    (x_front ?val)
    (bind ?temp 1)
    (choice-evaluation(y_left -1) (test (<= ?val ?temp ))(class ?x))
?c<-(choice-evaluation(y_left -1) (test(<= ?val ?temp ))(class ?x))
=>
(assert (es_result (classp 0) (classr ?x) (nr 1)))
(retract ?c))
```

and I get the error : ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::one
   (x_front ?val)
   (choice-evaluation (y_left -1) (test

I have tried a lot of things but I will always either get the error above or syntax error for defrules . I do not understand how I can have a comparison in defrules with multislot objects.

I tried creating a rule like the examples here :https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~sylee/courses/clips/advpattern.htm and they do work but it doesnt work for my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code which are easier to see if you ident the code:

```
(defrule MAIN::one
   (x_front ?val)
   (bind ?temp 1)
   (choice-evaluation (y_left -1) 
                      (test (<= ?val ?temp)) 
                      (class ?x))
   ?c <- (choice-evaluation (y_left -1) 
                            (test (<= ?val ?temp))
                            (class ?x))
   =>
   (assert (es_result (classp 0) (classr ?x) (nr 1)))
   (retract ?c))
```

You've placed test conditional elements inside choice-evaluation conditional elements so the parser treats the test symbols as slot names and since the choice-evaluation deftemplate has no slot named test you get an error. You'll also get an error for using class as a slot name since this slot is also not defined in the choice-evaluation deftemplate.

Also, (bind ?temp 1) will be treated as a fact pattern, not a function call. If you want to retrieve a value in the conditions of a rule, assert a fact containing that value and assign it to a variable using a pattern like the x_front pattern in your rule. Duplication of the choice-evaluation pattern serves no purpose--Just keep the 2nd one since it binds ?c to the fact-address matching the pattern which is need by the retract command in the actions of the rule.

Answer (score 0):

@Gary Riley thanks for your input it helped a lot!

```
    (choice-evaluation (x_front ?val) (y_left -1) (class ?x))
               (test (<= ?val 1 ))
              ?c <- (choice-evaluation (x_front ?val) (y_left -1) (class ?x))
=>
(assert (es_result (classp 0) (classr ?x) (nr 1)))
(retract ?c))
```

So turns out this is how it is supposed to be used. Leaving it here in case someone else in the future has a similar problem
credits : I. Xatziligeroudis